# FreeRadius 3 + sqlippool

Tags: ip, postgresql, freeradius

I have a basic configured FreeRadius in conjunction with Postgresql and Mikrotik. The SQL module is configured correctly and PPPoE authorization through the database works. I need to connect and configure the sqlippool module. At this point, I have problems because there are no detailed instructions on configuring this module on the Internet.
Here is a list of what I tried to do:

1. Specified the "postgresql" dialect in the sqlippool file
2. Connected the module
3. Created a radippool table via the PostgreSQL schema
4. Added the following lines to the database:

`INSERT INTO radippool (pool_name, framedipaddress) VALUES ('main_pool', '10.1.0.5');`

`INSERT INTO radippool (pool_name, framedipaddress) VALUES ('main_pool', '10.1.0.6');`

`INSERT INTO radcheck (username, attribute, op, value) VALUES ('tester', 'Cleartext-Password', ':=', 'test');`

`INSERT INTO radcheck (username, attribute, op, value) VALUES ('tester', 'Pool-Name', ':=', 'main_pool');`

Reboot. As a result - nothing. FreeRadius does not issue ip addresses from the pool, and I do not see any errors in the logs. Can you tell me what I did wrong? Do I need to connect something else, or did I make a mistake somewhere? Please tell a detailed sequence of actions for correct configuration of this module. I think this guide will help many beginners, since there is simply no detailed information.

UPDATE. Logs:

Ready to process requests

(0) Received Access-Request Id 19 from 10.1.0.1:53161 to 10.1.0.4:1812 length 198

(0)   Service-Type = Framed-User

(0)   Framed-Protocol = PPP

(0)   NAS-Port = 15728646

(0)   NAS-Port-Type = Ethernet

(0)   User-Name = "tester"

(0)   Calling-Station-Id = "C4:12:F5:D4:85:70"

(0)   Called-Station-Id = "myclients"

(0)   NAS-Port-Id = "ether3"

(0)   Acct-Session-Id = "81a00006"

(0)   MS-CHAP-Challenge = 0x97e9a21dabacee5e9c0384f778dc7915

(0)   MS-CHAP2-Response = 0x010029335f35cdd38e0fa6eab66e12022f47000000000000000078126d15554660d74add815846c50ab6353c7e0847952eac

(0)   NAS-Identifier = "MikroTik"

(0)   NAS-IP-Address = 10.1.0.1

(0) # Executing section authorize from file /etc/freeradius/3.0/sites-enabled/default

(0)   authorize {

(0)     policy filter_username {

(0)       if (&User-Name) {

(0)       if (&User-Name)  -> TRUE

(0)       if (&User-Name)  {

(0)         if (&User-Name =~ / /) {

(0)         if (&User-Name =~ / /)  -> FALSE

(0)         if (&User-Name =~ /@[^@]*@/ ) {

(0)         if (&User-Name =~ /@[^@]*@/ )  -> FALSE

(0)         if (&User-Name =~ /../ ) {

(0)         if (&User-Name =~ /../ )  -> FALSE

(0)         if ((&User-Name =~ /@/) && (&User-Name !~ /@(.+).(.+)$/))  {

(0)         if ((&User-Name =~ /@/) && (&User-Name !~ /@(.+).(.+)$/))   ->
FALSE

(0)         if (&User-Name =~ /.$/)  {

(0)         if (&User-Name =~ /.$/)   -> FALSE

(0)         if (&User-Name =~ /@./)  {

(0)         if (&User-Name =~ /@./)   -> FALSE

(0)       } # if (&User-Name)  = notfound

(0)     } # policy filter_username = notfound

(0)     [preprocess] = ok

(0)     [chap] = noop

(0) mschap: Found MS-CHAP attributes.  Setting 'Auth-Type  = mschap'

(0)     [mschap] = ok

(0)     [digest] = noop

(0) suffix: Checking for suffix after "@"

(0) suffix: No '@' in User-Name = "tester", looking up realm NULL

(0) suffix: No such realm "NULL"

(0)     [suffix] = noop

(0) eap: No EAP-Message, not doing EAP

(0)     [eap] = noop

(0) files: users: Matched entry DEFAULT at line 181

(0)     [files] = ok

(0) sql: EXPAND %{User-Name}

(0) sql:    --> tester

(0) sql: SQL-User-Name set to 'tester'
rlm_sql (sql): Reserved connection (1)

(0) sql: EXPAND SELECT id, UserName, Attribute, Value, Op FROM radcheck WHERE
Username = '%{SQL-User-Name}' ORDER BY id

(0) sql:    --> SELECT id, UserName, Attribute, Value, Op FROM radcheck WHERE Username = 'tester' ORDER BY id

(0) sql: Executing select query: SELECT id, UserName, Attribute, Value, Op FROM radcheck WHERE Username = 'tester' ORDER BY id
rlm_sql_postgresql: Status: PGRES_TUPLES_OK
rlm_sql_postgresql: query affected rows = 2 , fields = 5

(0) sql: User found in radcheck table

(0) sql: Conditional check items matched, merging assignment check items

(0) sql:   Cleartext-Password := "test"

(0) sql:   Pool-Name := "main_pool"

(0) sql: EXPAND SELECT id, UserName, Attribute, Value, Op FROM radreply WHERE Username = '%{SQL-User-Name}' ORDER BY id

(0) sql:    --> SELECT id, UserName, Attribute, Value, Op FROM radreply WHERE
Username = 'tester' ORDER BY id

(0) sql: Executing select query: SELECT id, UserName, Attribute, Value, Op FROM radreply WHERE Username = 'tester' ORDER BY id
rlm_sql_postgresql: Status: PGRES_TUPLES_OK
rlm_sql_postgresql: query affected rows = 0 , fields = 5

(0) sql: EXPAND SELECT GroupName FROM radusergroup WHERE UserName='%{SQL-User-Name}' ORDER BY priority

(0) sql:    --> SELECT GroupName FROM radusergroup WHERE UserName='tester' ORDER BY priority

(0) sql: Executing select query: SELECT GroupName FROM radusergroup WHERE
UserName='tester' ORDER BY priority
rlm_sql_postgresql: Status: PGRES_TUPLES_OK
rlm_sql_postgresql: query affected rows = 0 , fields = 1

(0) sql: User not found in any groups
rlm_sql (sql): Released connection (1)
Need 4 more connections to reach 10 spares
rlm_sql (sql): Opening additional connection (6), 1 of 26 pending slots used
rlm_sql_postgresql: Connecting using parameters: dbname='radius' host='localhost' port=5432 user='radius' password='radpass'
Connected to database 'radius' on 'localhost' server version 110007, protocol version 3, backend PID 28624

(0)     [sql] = ok

(0)     [expiration] = noop

(0)     [logintime] = noop

(0) pap: WARNING: Auth-Type already set.  Not setting to PAP

(0)     [pap] = noop

(0)   } # authorize = ok

(0) Found Auth-Type = mschap

(0) # Executing group from file /etc/freeradius/3.0/sites-enabled/default

(0)   authenticate {

(0) mschap: Found Cleartext-Password, hashing to create NT-Password

(0) mschap: Found Cleartext-Password, hashing to create LM-Password

(0) mschap: Creating challenge hash with username: tester

(0) mschap: Client is using MS-CHAPv2

(0) mschap: Adding MS-CHAPv2 MPPE keys

(0)     [mschap] = ok

(0)   } # authenticate = ok

(0) # Executing section post-auth from file /etc/freeradius/3.0/sites-enabled/default

(0)   post-auth {

(0)     update {

(0)       No attributes updated

(0)     } # update = noop

(0) sql: EXPAND .query

(0) sql:    --> .query

(0) sql: Using query template 'query'
rlm_sql (sql): Reserved connection (2)

(0) sql: EXPAND %{User-Name}

(0) sql:    --> tester

(0) sql: SQL-User-Name set to 'tester'

(0) sql: EXPAND INSERT INTO radpostauth (username, pass, reply, authdate) VALUES('%{User-Name}', '%{%{User-Password}:-Chap-Password}', '%{reply:Packet-Type}', NOW())

(0) sql:    --> INSERT INTO radpostauth (username, pass, reply, authdate) VALUES('tester', 'Chap-Password', 'Access-Accept', NOW())

(0) sql: Executing query: INSERT INTO radpostauth (username, pass, reply, authdate) VALUES('tester', 'Chap-Password', 'Access-Accept', NOW())
rlm_sql_postgresql: Status: PGRES_COMMAND_OK
rlm_sql_postgresql: query affected rows = 1

(0) sql: SQL query returned: success

(0) sql: 1 record(s) updated
rlm_sql (sql): Released connection (2)

(0)     [sql] = ok

(0)     [exec] = noop

(0)     policy remove_reply_message_if_eap {

(0)       if (&reply:EAP-Message && &reply:Reply-Message) {

(0)       if (&reply:EAP-Message && &reply:Reply-Message)  -> FALSE

(0)       else {

(0)         [noop] = noop

(0)       } # else = noop

(0)     } # policy remove_reply_message_if_eap = noop

(0)   } # post-auth = ok

(0) Sent Access-Accept Id 19 from 10.1.0.4:1812 to 10.1.0.1:53161 length 0

(0)   Framed-Protocol = PPP

(0)   Framed-Compression = Van-Jacobson-TCP-IP

(0)   MS-CHAP2-Success = 0x01533d42443236373932353546324538304641374430424235463938333445314331454330323244463233

(0)   MS-MPPE-Recv-Key = 0xf03b52e2c28c093649b396d6e2b16945

(0)   MS-MPPE-Send-Key = 0xb4d2427c437eca3f444403b060bc59f7

(0)   MS-MPPE-Encryption-Policy = Encryption-Allowed

(0)   MS-MPPE-Encryption-Types = RC4-40or128-bit-Allowed

(0) Finished request
Waking up in 4.9 seconds.

(1) Received Accounting-Request Id 20 from 10.1.0.1:48965 to 10.1.0.4:1813 length 146

(1)   Service-Type = Framed-User

(1)   Framed-Protocol = PPP

(1)   NAS-Port = 15728646

(1)   NAS-Port-Type = Ethernet

(1)   User-Name = "tester"

(1)   Calling-Station-Id = "C4:12:F5:D4:85:70"

(1)   Called-Station-Id = "myclients"

(1)   NAS-Port-Id = "ether3"

(1)   Acct-Session-Id = "81a00006"

(1)   Framed-IP-Address = 10.1.0.252

(1)   Acct-Authentic = RADIUS

(1)   Event-Timestamp = "Jul 13 2020 14:57:41 +08"

(1)   Acct-Status-Type = Start

(1)   NAS-Identifier = "MikroTik"

(1)   Acct-Delay-Time = 0

(1)   NAS-IP-Address = 10.1.0.1

(1) # Executing section preacct from file /etc/freeradius/3.0/sites-enabled/default

(1)   preacct {

(1)     [preprocess] = ok

(1)     policy acct_unique {

(1)       update request {

(1)         &Tmp-String-9 := "ai:"

(1)       } # update request = noop

(1)       if (("%{hex:&Class}" =~ /^%{hex:&Tmp-String-9}/) &&       ("%{string:&Class}" =~ /^ai:([0-9a-f]{32})/i)) {

(1)       EXPAND %{hex:&Class}

(1)          -->

(1)       EXPAND ^%{hex:&Tmp-String-9}

(1)          --> ^61693a

(1)       if (("%{hex:&Class}" =~ /^%{hex:&Tmp-String-9}/) &&       ("%{string:&Class}" =~ /^ai:([0-9a-f]{32})/i))  -> FALSE

(1)       else {

(1)         update request {

(1)           EXPAND %{md5:%{User-Name},%{Acct-Session-ID},%{%{NAS-IPv6-Address}:-%{NAS-IP-Address}},%{NAS-Identifier},%{NAS-Port-ID},%{NAS-Port}}

(1)              --> 9b06bc7d71ce816cb361a7625387ab61

(1)           &Acct-Unique-Session-Id := 9b06bc7d71ce816cb361a7625387ab61

(1)         } # update request = noop

(1)       } # else = noop

(1)     } # policy acct_unique = noop

(1) suffix: Checking for suffix after "@"

(1) suffix: No '@' in User-Name = "tester", looking up realm NULL

(1) suffix: No such realm "NULL"

(1)     [suffix] = noop

(1)     [files] = noop

(1)   } # preacct = ok

(1) # Executing section accounting from file /etc/freeradius/3.0/sites-enabled/default

(1)   accounting {

(1) detail: EXPAND /var/log/freeradius/radacct/%{%{Packet-Src-IP-Address}:-%{Packet-Src-IPv6-Address}}/detail-%Y%m%d

(1) detail:    --> /var/log/freeradius/radacct/10.1.0.1/detail-20200713

(1) detail: /var/log/freeradius/radacct/%{%{Packet-Src-IP-Address}:-%{Packet-Src-IPv6-Address}}/detail-%Y%m%d expands to /var/log/freeradius/radacct/10.1.0.1/detail-20200713

(1) detail: EXPAND %t

(1) detail:    --> Mon Jul 13 14:57:45 2020

(1)     [detail] = ok

(1)     [unix] = ok

(1) sql: EXPAND %{tolower:type.%{%{Acct-Status-Type}:-none}.query}

(1) sql:    --> type.start.query

(1) sql: Using query template 'query'
rlm_sql (sql): Reserved connection (3)

(1) sql: EXPAND %{User-Name}

(1) sql:    --> tester

(1) sql: SQL-User-Name set to 'tester'

(1) sql: EXPAND INSERT INTO radacct (AcctSessionId, AcctUniqueId, UserName, Realm, NASIPAddress, NASPortId, NASPortType, AcctStartTime, AcctUpdateTime, AcctStopTime, AcctSessionTime, AcctAuthentic, ConnectInfo_start, ConnectInfo_Stop, AcctInputOctets, AcctOutputOctets, CalledStationId, CallingStationId, AcctTerminateCause, ServiceType, FramedProtocol, FramedIpAddress) VALUES('%{Acct-Session-Id}', '%{Acct-Unique-Session-Id}', '%{SQL-User-Name}', NULLIF('%{Realm}', ''), '%{%{NAS-IPv6-Address}:-%{NAS-IP-Address}}', NULLIF('%{%{NAS-Port-ID}:-%{NAS-Port}}', ''), '%{NAS-Port-Type}', TO_TIMESTAMP(%{integer:Event-Timestamp}), TO_TIMESTAMP(%{integer:Event-Timestamp}), NULL, 0, '%{Acct-Authentic}', '%{Connect-Info}', NULL, 0, 0, '%{Called-Station-Id}', '%{Calling-Station-Id}', NULL, '%{Service-Type}', '%{Framed-Protocol}', NULLIF('%{Framed-IP-Address}', '')::inet)

(1) sql:    --> INSERT INTO radacct (AcctSessionId, AcctUniqueId, UserName, Realm, NASIPAddress, NASPortId, NASPortType, AcctStartTime, AcctUpdateTime, AcctStopTime, AcctSessionTime, AcctAuthentic, ConnectInfo_start, ConnectInfo_Stop, AcctInputOctets, AcctOutputOctets, CalledStationId, CallingStationId, AcctTerminateCause, ServiceType, FramedProtocol, FramedIpAddress) VALUES('81a00006', '9b06bc7d71ce816cb361a7625387ab61', 'tester', NULLIF('', ''), '10.1.0.1', NULLIF('ether3', ''), 'Ethernet', TO_TIMESTAMP(1594623461), TO_TIMESTAMP(1594623461), NULL, 0, 'RADIUS', '', NULL, 0, 0, 'myclients', 'C4:12:F5:D4:85:70', NULL, 'Framed-User', 'PPP', NULLIF('10.1.0.252', '')::inet)

(1) sql: Executing query: INSERT INTO radacct (AcctSessionId, AcctUniqueId, UserName, Realm, NASIPAddress, NASPortId, NASPortType, AcctStartTime, AcctUpdateTime, AcctStopTime, AcctSessionTime, AcctAuthentic, ConnectInfo_start, ConnectInfo_Stop, AcctInputOctets, AcctOutputOctets, CalledStationId, CallingStationId, AcctTerminateCause, ServiceType, FramedProtocol, FramedIpAddress) VALUES('81a00006', '9b06bc7d71ce816cb361a7625387ab61', 'tester', NULLIF('', ''), '10.1.0.1', NULLIF('ether3', ''), 'Ethernet', TO_TIMESTAMP(1594623461), TO_TIMESTAMP(1594623461), NULL, 0, 'RADIUS', '', NULL, 0, 0, 'myclients', 'C4:12:F5:D4:85:70', NULL, 'Framed-User', 'PPP', NULLIF('10.1.0.252', '')::inet)
rlm_sql_postgresql: Status: PGRES_COMMAND_OK
rlm_sql_postgresql: query affected rows = 1

(1) sql: SQL query returned: success

(1) sql: 1 record(s) updated
rlm_sql (sql): Released connection (3)

(1)     [sql] = ok

(1)     [exec] = noop

(1) attr_filter.accounting_response: EXPAND %{User-Name}

(1) attr_filter.accounting_response:    --> tester

(1) attr_filter.accounting_response: Matched entry DEFAULT at line 12

(1)     [attr_filter.accounting_response] = updated

(1)   } # accounting = updated

(1) Sent Accounting-Response Id 20 from 10.1.0.4:1813 to 10.1.0.1:48965 length 0

(1) Finished request

(1) Cleaning up request packet ID 20 with timestamp +5
Waking up in 4.9 seconds.

(0) Cleaning up request packet ID 19 with timestamp +5
Ready to process requests

Comment: Run `radiusd -X` with the output to a file, try again, and then inspect the log entries.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I have already looked at the logs (read the question carefully). There is nothing in them, just a line with a notification that this module is loaded

Comment: There are no logs in your question! You should have significantly more than one line showing! Did you actually run `radiusd -X`?

Comment: @MichaelHampton sry, my bad. Logs here. I should have attached the logs right away. In any case I don't see anything here that concerns this issue. Help me pls xD